# Define a function replic lt in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Define a function replic lt in haskell that replicates each element in lt into a list. If the element is in the kth position of lt, the resulting list contains k copies of the same element. You must define this function using the higher-order function of `map`.

E.g.

```
> replic [2,3,4,7,6]
[[2], [3,3], [4,4,4], [7,7,7,7], [6,6,6,6,6]]
```

My Approach but there are some problem:

```
maps f [] = []
maps f (x:xs) = f [x] : maps f xs

rep a b
  |b==0 = []
  |b<0 = error "negative value"
  |otherwise = a ++ rep a (b-1)

replicas []=[]
replicas (x:xs) = rep (x:xs) xs

replic (x:xs) = maps replicas (x:xs)
```

If I want to use this program how can I modify to get the correct result?
Please help me. :(

```
maps f [] = []
maps f (x:xs) = f [x] : maps f xs

rep a b
  |b==0 = []
  |b<0 = error "negative value"
  |otherwise = a ++ rep a (b-1)

replicas []=[]
replicas (x:xs) = rep (x:xs) xs

replic (x:xs) = maps replicas (x:xs)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with zipWith.        replic lt = zipWith replicate [1..] lt     But I have to do it with map hof.

Comment: Here's a hint: use `zip` instead of `zipWith`, and then use `map` on the result.

Comment: maps f [] = []
maps f (x:xs) = f [x] : maps f xs

rep a b
  |b==0 = []
  |b<0 = error "negative value"
  |otherwise = a ++ rep a (b-1)

replicas []=[]
replicas (x:xs) = rep (x:xs) xs

replic (x:xs) = maps replicas (x:xs)

Comment: but in the above code it's taking the each element and printing that many times.

Comment: put your work in the problem definition section. Not the comment section.

Comment: "but there are some problem:" doesn't help us help you. You tell us what you are trying to accomplish. Then you tell us what you did to try. Then you tell us exactly where you are having a problem. Then we can help.

Comment: Also , pay attention to what I did to fix your formatting. Please be mindful, and help us help you by being clear.

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelLitchard for formatting. I will take care of this from the next time onwards.

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this problem. I am new to Haskell and trying to solve this but unable to do it.

Comment: It's good to get in the habit of giving type signatures to your functions. You've made a couple of mistakes here that I think would be easier for you to see if you had given each of your functions type signatures. Try giving each of `maps`, `rep`, `replicas`, and `replic` the signatures that you think they ought to have, and see if the resulting errors clear any of your problems up.

Comment: Missing binding for variable "replicate" in type signature. What does it mean? what can be the problem?

Comment: Can't help you with errors when you don't update your code in the question. You most certainly didn't get that error from the code that's there.

Comment: If you give a type signature `replicate::Int -> [a] -> [a]`, Haskell is expecting you to follow that with a definition of `replicate`. Instead, you followed it with a definition of `replic`. If you want to use `replicate` from the prelude, you don't need to declare its type; just use it. If you want to define your own `replicate`, you have to actually do that.

Comment: @user11228628: I didn't get what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Jesica, in the code in your last edit, the first line is a type signature for `replicate`, and the second line is a definition for `replic`, and the name `replic` is not the same as the name `replicate`. It's not allowed to define a type signature that isn't paired with a definition for the same name, so why did you write that? What were you trying to say with the `replicate` signature?

Comment: @user11228628, why do you recommend `zip` instead of `zipWith`? The obvious solution here is a direct application of `zipWith`.

Comment: `import Data.List`

`replic xs = group $ go 1 xs`
    `where go _ [] = []`
          `go i (x:xs) = (take i $ repeat x) ++ go (i + 1) xs`

Comment: @dfeuer, only because OP repeatedly specified that `map` had to be involved. In the second comment, OP showed that she was aware of the direct `zipWith` solution but that it wouldn't do because it doesn't use `map`.

Comment: @user11228628, ah, I missed that. By that point, it's just time to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is solve the problem using explicit recursion and then try to detect places where you can replace certain parts of the recursion with a higher-order function. Here are some hints for creating an explicitly recursive version:

1. Give `replic` a type signature and a base case:

   ```
   replic :: [a] -> [[a]]
   replic [] = ...
   replic (x:xs) = ...
   ```

   If the result were just `[ [1], [2], [3], ... ]` and not `[ [1], [2,2], [3,3,3], ... ]`, you could write `[x] : replic xs` as the recursive function body. But instead you need to create *n* copies of `x`, but you don't have access to any variable `n`. So you need to somehow introduce a counter.
2. Since `replic` must take an `[a]` and return an `[[a]]`, there is no room in its type signature for a counter, so you could make a helper function with an extra accumulating argument:

   ```
   replic :: [a] -> [[a]]
   replic = replic' 1

   replic' :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
   replic' n [] = ...
   replic' n (x:xs) = ...
   ```
3. Now you have the input for creating `n` copies of `x`, so your `rep` function will come handy:

   ```
   rep :: a -> Int -> [a]
   rep x n
     | n > 0  = x : rep x (n-1)
     | otherwise = []
   ```

---

As for using higher-order functions to solve this, it's a little difficult to transform

```
[ 1, 3, 7, ... ]
```

into

```
[ [1], [3,3], [7,7,7], ... ]
```

with `map` because `map` performs the *same* transformation on each element, and

```
1 ~> [1]
3 ~> [3,3]
7 ~> [7,7,7]
```

are not products of the same transformation, because *extra* information is required (the position in the list). The only way you can do this with `map` is to make the position in the list a part of the input to the function you're mapping with. If, for example you had to transform

```
[ (1,1), (3,2), (7,3), ... ]
```

into

```
[ [1], [3,3], [7,7,7], ... ]
```

then you could do this with `map` and your `rep`.

But you cannot construct this `[ (1,1), (3,2), (7,3), ... ]` with `map`.

You'd have to either do this using an explicitly recursive function, or with `` (`zip` [1..]) ``.

As others have recommended, `zipWith` combines `map` and `zip`.